# Call a method from the Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm newbie to Vue.js

I just want to call a method from a component:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        message: {
            props: ['createdat'],
            template: '
            <div>
              {{ postedOnA(createdat) }}
              {{ postedOnB(createdat) }}
            </div>',
        },
        methods: {
            postedOnA: function (createdat) {
                var date = new Date(createdat);
                return date.getHours() + ' ' + date.getMinutes();
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        postedOnB: function(createdat) {
            var date = new Date(createdat);
            return date.getHours() + ' ' + date.getMinutes();
        }
    }
})
```

I have also tried to call a component method, but that is not working too

Thanks

Comment: Bring the 'methods' to 'message' component's level, just after the template.

Comment: @Deepak, thanks a lot, that worked. But how can I call postedOnB() ??

Comment: Parth what exactly are you trying to do over here. Your functions look more like filters to me. Please refer https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Filters

Comment: yes, it seems like a filter is more appropriate over here. Basically, I'm just formatting the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create filters for formatting.

In your case:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        message: {
            props: ['createdat'],
            template: '
            <div>
              {{ createdat | formatdate }}
            </div>',
        }
    },
    filters: {
      formatdate: function (value) {
         var date = new Date(value);
         return date.getHours() + ' ' + date.getMinutes();
      }
    }
})
```

Read more here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Comment: Would be good if you can show me that how can I access a filter which is at the root level of Vue instance not on the component level.

Comment: Above example sets the filter on the root instance which can be accessed from any component.

Comment: I tried that but didn't work globally: [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: formatdate 
(found in <Anonymous> - use the "name" option for better debugging messages.)

Comment: Please provide a fiddle, I will look into it. I have tested the above code, it works in fiddle.